# Active admin multiple select filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activeadmin

I'm looking to make a filter on my admin page for a user to show users who have both Subject_A and Subject_B.

Using the following line of code I've been able to filter for the users who have either Subject_A or Subject_B or both.

```
filter :universities, as: :select, multiple: true
```

Is there a way to create a filter using Active Admin to filter for users that only have both Subject_A **and** Subject_B?

Answer (score 11):

`multiple: true` never worked for me. The following did however:

```
filter :section, label: 'Category', 
  as: :select, input_html: { multiple: true }, 
  collection: User.categories
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

> filter :universities_and_universities, as: :select, multiple: true

This is not the perfect solution but it should works fine

Comment: I'm getting an `undefined method universities_and_universities_cont for Ransack` when I try that unfortunately

Comment: You don't need to put the `_cont`

Comment: I test it with the gem activeAdmin

Comment: Still running into errors unfortunately.

`undefined method universities_or_universities_in for Ransack::Search<class: Tutor, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search`